# Typescript type restrictions behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm relatively new to the Typescript world, and I'm just working on a test app to get my self used to it. So I have this weird (?) issue with type restriction 'not working'.

I have an array defined in a class like member field this:

`listings: Array<ICryptListingItem> = [];`

And the interface is:

```
export interface ICryptListingItem {
  name: string;
  something: number;
}
```

Why is the compiler fine with doing:

```
  this.listings = listings.data.map((listing) => {
      return {
        name: listing.name
      }
    });
```

The objects returned from **listings.data.map** is not implementing the interface the array has as it's type? What am I not getting here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `listings`? If you have lambda expression as ` (listings) => ... ` then `listings` is by default `any`, if you define type of any variable as `any` then typescript will not enforce any restrictions. If you have lambda like `(listings: Array<ICryptListingItem>)` then typescript will give you errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does handle this automatically; your code sample is missing some information. For example:

```
export interface ICryptListingItem {
    name: string;
    something: number;
}

class MyThing {
    listings: Array<ICryptListingItem> = [];

    doSomething() {
        const listings = {
            data: [
                { name: "the keeper" },
                { name: "the seeker" }
            ]
        };

        // Error here, as expected
        this.listings = listings.data.map((listing) => {
            return {
                name: listing.name
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Probably the type of either `listings` or `listings.data` is `any`, so the result of the `map` call is also `any`; `any` is then always an allowed type to assign to `this.listings`.

Comment: Alright, i'm honestly a bit confused. Isn't this exactly what typescripts typesafety  is designed to prevent?

Comment: How does TypeScript know that `listing.data.map` means `Array.map`, and not `Google.map` or `Bing.map`, if you haven't told it?